# Highcharts remove() Inconsistencies

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart and I simply want to remove a bar from it.  Sounds simple, but the remove() method works differently depending on which data point I access.

Something like...

```
chart.series[0].data[0].remove();
```

...works nicely.  Removes the bar and the category associated with the bar.  Now a small change:

```
chart.series[0].data[1].remove();
```

and while the bar is removed the category is not.  Trying to modify the categories and use setCategory does not alleviate the issue.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/FxY63/2/

What kind of magic do I need to cast to so that pressing "Remove Point 2" properly cleans up the categories array and leaves the correct number of tics on the y-axis?

Comment: The first category is not removed in this case, only placed outside the view area. You can see the category move into view if the first point is added again http://jsfiddle.net/FxY63/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the only solution I could come up with from my searching.  Storing your categories and data into arrays, and depending on the index you want to remove splice the data/category out of the arrays and re-set the category/data to the chart causing it to redraw with the new data.

Fiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/3dcbY/

```
var categories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

// button handler
$('#button1').click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.data.length) {
        categories.splice(0,1);
        data.splice(0,1);

        series.setData(data);
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    }
});

// button handler
$('#button2').click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.data.length) {
        categories.splice(1,1);
        data.splice(1,1);

        series.setData(data);
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I modified this slightly so it didn't rely on globals and it works great!